# Vectorized function depends on index value/row number

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I'm trying to use np.where() or np.select() on a dataframe, in such a way where the output depends on which row of the dataframe I'm on. For example,

```
np.where(condition, myfunc(df.iloc[:rownumber]), 0)
```

where `myfunc` acts on a version of the dataframe where everything past the current row is truncated, such that the current row is the last row of this truncated dataframe. Is there a way to implement this? How can I extract the row number or the index value of the row that I am on?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but have you consider using rolling with a large window (size of the data frame)? 
Alternatively, for getting the row number, maybe just reset the index and use it

Comment: What would I have to do to get the row number after resetting the index? If I don't reset it I could still probably do something like ```df.loc[:row]```